# RedirectMatch or Rewrite Rule for 301 Redirects of *.html to non-extension path

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've searched everywhere, including SO, can't quite find the answer to this question:

I'd like to set up a 301 redirect such that:

```
www.mysite.com/some-page.html
```

redirects to

```
www.mysite.com/some-page/
```

I'm using the below in my htaccess file (it's a WordPress site):

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ $1

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**The problem**
If I visit `www.mysite.com/`, it redirects to `www.mysite.com/index`

(Note: If I visite `www.mysite.com/some-page.html`, it *does work* and redirects to `www.mysite.com/some-page/`)

Any advise on how to make this work? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RedirectMatch` is part of mod_alias, and the `RewriteRule` stuff is part of mod_rewrite. Both modules will get applied to the same URI at different points of the processing pipeline. That means you can't just tell apache to stop what it's doing and redirect. The mod_rewrite part will still get applied regardless.

To deal with this, just stick with using mod_rewrite instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html /$1/ [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Phenomenal.  It looks so easy when someone knows what they are doing, but nothing I tried quite got it.  Thank you!